# Kotlin Remove all non alphanumeric characters

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to remove all non alphanumeric characters from a string.

I tried using `replace()` with a regex as followed:

```
var answer = answerEditText.text.toString()
Log.d("debug", answer)
answer = answer.replace("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "").toLowerCase()
Log.d("debug", answer)
```

> D/debug: Test. ,replace
>
> D/debug: test. ,replace

Why are the punctuation characters still present? How to get only the alphanumeric characters?

Comment: I think you want `replaceAll`?

Comment: `String.replace` searches for a literal string, while `String.replaceAll` searches for a regular expression.

Comment: You have to create a regex object. Otherwise you're just replacing occurrences of the literal string `[^A-Za-z0-9 ]` which is obviously not in your input.

Comment: Although my suggestion (`replaceAll`) would work in Java, Kotlin has its own `String` class, which does not contain a definition for `replaceAll`. So please disregard my suggestion.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You need to create a regex object

```
var answer = "Test. ,replace"
println(answer)
answer = answer.replace("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "") // doesn't work
println(answer)
val re = Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]")
answer = re.replace(answer, "") // works
println(answer)
```

Try it online: https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/ttqm0r6lisi743f2dltveid1u9/2olerk6jvb10l03q6bkk1lapjn

Comment: Going with `val answer = answerEditText.text.toString().replace("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]".toRegex(), "").toLowerCase()`

Comment: Alternatively `(?i)[^\\w\\d ]` - case insensitive checks using \w and \d instead of manually typing the matches

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, Swift also has extension functions. :)

Comment: @CoolMind Many languages do. My comment was with regards to the answer above, not in general applicable to all the languages that exist.

Answer (score 94):

The standard library of Kotlin is beautiful like this.  Just use [String.filter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/filter.html) combined with [Char.isLetterOrDigit](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-letter-or-digit.html), like this:

```
val stringToFilter = "A1.2-b3_4C"
val stringWithOnlyDigits = stringToFilter.filter { it.isLetterOrDigit() }
println(stringWithOnlyDigits) //Prints out "A12b34C"
```

Comment: Fun fact. The Pi symbol does not get filtered out with this filter. It is seen as a letter since it's a letter in the greek alphabet. TIL

Answer (score 25):

You need to create a regex, this can be done by `str.toRegex()` before calling `replace`

```
val string = "AsAABa3a35e8tfyz.a6ax7xe"
string = string.replace(("[^\\d.]").toRegex(), "")
```

result: 3358.67

In case you need to handle words W and spaces

```
var string = "Test in@@ #Kot$#lin   FaaFS@@#$%^&StraßeFe.__525448=="
    string = string.replace(("[^\\w\\d ]").toRegex(), "")
    println(string)
```

result: Test in Kotlin   FaaFSStraeFe__525448

Comment: The question was about  *I am trying to remove all non alphanumeric characters from a string.* This regexp does something different

Comment: Please check my edited answer, but I am not sure how are you considering some special characters like à ß? In my answer it will remove them too...
thanks

Comment: Better! I added a line about `toRegx()` as a intro

Answer (score 19):

I find this to be much more succinct and maintainable.  Could be that the previous answers were made before these extensions were added?

```
val alphaNumericString = someString.toCharArray()
   .filter { it.isLetterOrDigit() }
   .joinToString(separator = "")
```

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing what the performance of this was once reduced to bytecode

Comment: This seems wasteful as it creates two temporary arrays, and doesn't really increase maintainability in any real sense. It just "feels" nice because it's "functional".

Answer (score 15):

I think it's easiest way:

```
fun String.toNumericString() = this.filter { it.isDigit() }
```

Answer (score 11):

```
fun String.digitsOnly(): String{
    val regex = Regex("[^0-9]")
    return regex.replace(this, "")
}
fun String.alphaNumericOnly(): String{
    val regex = Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]")
    return regex.replace(this, "")
}
```

Usage:

```
val alphaNumeric = "my string #$".alphaNumericOnly()
```

Comment: For digits-only, is this better, perhaps: `"[^0-9+]".toRegex()` ? They are the same in terms of what they do, though, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can try without regex, for example:

```
val ranges = ('0'..'9') + ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z')
val escaped = "1! at __ 2? at 345..0986 ZOk".filter { it in ranges }
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin thinks you substituting string, but not regex, so you should help a little bit to choose right method signature with regex as a first argument.

Use Regex type explicitly instead of string:

```
"[^A-Za-z0-9 ]".toRegex()
```

or tell that you are passing named regex parameter:

```
answer.replace(regex = "[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "")
```

and in this case kotlin wont compile unless you pass real regex, not string