# Extract numbers from a string kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

`String.replaceAll` is not running and is unsupported in Kotlin. So I suggest a demo example, I hope it help.

```
var string = "vsdhfnmsdbvfuf121535435aewr"  
string.replace("[^0-9]".toRegex(), "")
```

Comment: can the string contain multiple numbers (scattered across the string) or just one?

Comment: could we help you?

Answer (score 111):

You could also take advantage of Kotlin's String.filter:

```
var string = "vsdhfnmsdbvfuf121535435aewr"
var result = string.filter { it.isDigit() }
```

I got this from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57316352

Comment: If the input has . ,Then ?

Comment: A simple unit test can help you figure out how to include a period: `var result = string.filter { it.isDigit() || it == '.'}`

Comment: I like the way kotlin can do thinks like this. Extension function on `Char` class for this operation is great for readibility.

Comment: @jj. you don't need to do that, just divider the output by 100, and you will get your decimal back

Answer (score 7):

Your code is working fine. Here `string` is immutable. So it's value can't be changed. But you can assign another variable to the replaced string.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var string = "vsdhfnmsdbvfuf121535435aewr"
    var res = string.replace("[^0-9]".toRegex(), "")
    println(res)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`replace` will not mutate the String `str`, that's why it is ok for `str` to be immutable (`val`) which it should be.

```
val str = "vsdhfnmsdbvfuf121535435aewr"
val num = str.replace(Regex("[^0-9]"), "")
println(num)
```

Output:

> 4545121535435

---

Since the title of your questions reads "numbers": In case you have multiple numbers scattered across the String you can use [Regex.findAll](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find-all.html). This is also a more fail safe solution because if you just remove what is around numbers then you might end up interpreting "a1b2c3" as "123" instead of as "[1 ,2 ,3]".

```
val str = "vsdhfn4545msdbvfuf121535435aewr"
val numbers = Regex("[0-9]+").findAll(str)
        .map(MatchResult::value)
        .toList()

println(numbers)
```

Output:

> [4545, 121535435]

Answer (score 4):

For some cases like if the text contains formatted amount, then the above answers might fail. For example, if the text is "*Rs. 1,00,000.00*" and if we only filter **.** and **digit**, then the output we get is .100000.00 this will be a wrong amount. So better first extract the string between digits and then filter for digit and Dot.

```
    fun String.getAmount(): String {
    return substring(indexOfFirst { it.isDigit() }, indexOfLast { it.isDigit() } + 1)
        .filter { it.isDigit() || it == '.' }
    }
```

Following cases will be covered using above code

> ```
>   println("Rs. 123".getAmount())
>   println("Rs. 123.23".getAmount())
>   println("Rs. 123.23/-".getAmount())
>   println("INR123.23".getAmount())
>   println("123.23INR".getAmount())
>   println("$100,000.00".getAmount())
>   println("Rs.100,000.00".getAmount())
> ```

Comment: You mean to say that stripping "Rs. 1,00,000.00" would end up with 10000000, not 100000. But thats ok, as it would be a bankers value, it's in cents, so just divide by 100, and you get 100000.00.

Comment: @BrillPappin If this is the case, how can we handle Rs. 123 and Rs. 123.00? I have explained the limitations of the regex method and the filtering only digits method.

Comment: Rs. 123 is invalid, or rather is seen as 1.23, but rs 123.00 would be seen as 12300. This is expected. If you are converting input, you want it to work this way. As the user types they are adding cents. The other potential use is parsing a bunch of corrupt data. In that case you'd want to fix the data first.

Answer (score 3):

The `replace` method returns a new `String`, not modify the base. You can try this [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/), and will work for you.

```
var s1 = "vsdhfnmsdbvfuf121535435aewr"  
var s2 = s1.replace("[^0-9]".toRegex(), "")
print(s2)
```

Answer (score 3):

if you looking for take out the numbers here is the solution

```
var string = "vsdhfnmsdbvfuf121535435aewr"
var result = string.filter { it.isLetter() }
```

instead of .isdigit type .isletter and it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

The replace function does not modify your string, but it return a new string. Your code will be fine:

- `val result = replace("[^0-9]".toRegex(), "")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

**Code**

```
  try {
        val p = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
        var m = p.matcher("string1234more567string890")
         while (m.find()) {
           System.out.println(m.group())
          }
      }catch (ex:java.lang.Exception){
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this we will get result

```
val digit:Int = Regex("[^0-9]").replace(bindAyatSearch.ayatSearchSp.selectedItem.toString(), "").toInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/tiksem/KotlinSpirit library

```
string.replaceAll(int, "")
```