# How do I remove all separator characters from a string in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to sanitize a QR code output.
The value I am trying to send via Retrofit is

010868193700666621762185642311216939172106131020190603

but OKHttp log show

```
example.com/endpoint/etc/&Qrcode=%1D010868193700666621762185642311216939%1D172106131020190603
```

When I use this *.trim().replace("\u00D", "")*

```
example.com/endpoint/etc/&Qrcode=010868193700666621762185642311216939%1D172106131020190603
```

How do I remove those unwanted characters?

Comment: You can use Kotlin's String.filter
Reference :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812220/extract-numbers-from-a-string-kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://howtodoinjava.com/regex/java-clean-ascii-text-non-printable-chars/
This here solved my problem.
I converted it to an extension in Kotlin like this

```
val String.cleanTextContent: String
    get() {
        // strips off all non-ASCII characters
        var text = this
        text = text.replace("[^\\x00-\\x7F]".toRegex(), "")

        // erases all the ASCII control characters
        text = text.replace("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]".toRegex(), "")

        // removes non-printable characters from Unicode
        text = text.replace("\\p{C}".toRegex(), "")
        return text.trim()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below to collect only digits from the string.

```
var result = string.filter { it.isDigit() }
```

Comment: this example didn't show but my input may contain a-zA-Z+-

Comment: whats about `answer.replace(regex = "[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "")`

Comment: Please let me know what all characters you need to support?

Comment: Yes I thought about it and was going for this but, like I said it may contain + - these and I cannot know

Comment: you need to support + and - too rt?

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/regex/java-clean-ascii-text-non-printable-chars/ I am trying this and seems to be working for me but I should test some more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217135/discussion-between-shalu-t-d-and-lutfitekin).